# AtomicInteger.compareAndSet that returns the original value, not a boolean

Tags: java, atomic, compare-and-swap, atomicinteger

Java's `AtomicInteger` offers [`public final boolean compareAndSet(int expect, int update)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-). If `false` is returned, I would like to know what the value actually was at the time when the comparison failed. Is this possible in Java?

In .Net, there's [`public static int CompareExchange(ref int location1, int value, int comparand)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx), which always returns the original value.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getAndCompareAndSet(AtomicInteger ai, int expected, int update) {
  while (true) {
    int old = ai.get();
    if (old != expected) {
      return old;
    } else if (ai.compareAndSet(old, update)) {
      return old;
    }
  }
}
```

(This sort of loop is how most operations on `AtomicInteger` are implemented: loops of get, do some logic, try compare-and-set.)

Comment: I wonder if that's what .Net does internally as well, or if .Net can do all that atomically in one go, which would seem to be faster. Not sure if some such operation exists on the machine level.

Comment: x86 has a single instruction for this: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_41.html

Comment: (Please ignore -> )That's not really atomic, though. Between `ai.get()` and `ai.compareAndSet()`, the stored value may have been changed by another thread.

Comment: @vanza, of course it may be.  That's why we only return if `compareAndSet` returns `true`, in which case `ai` didn't change in between.  This is exactly what e.g. `AtomicInteger.getAndAdd` does.

Comment: My bad, I missed the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not expose such a method. What's more, the Oracle implementation uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` to do the native CAS operation and that type doesn't expose it either.

One option is to just call `get()` if `compareAndSet` returned `false`. However, by the time you check it, the actual value of the `AtomicInteger` might have changed. There's not much you can do with it. This is true for `Interlocked` methods as well. You'd have to clarify what you want to do with that value to go any further.